# I have installed ROS (jade) in ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. Many of the demo packages mentioned in the tutorial are not being located by the installed ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First I used *$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-husky-navigation* and it executed successfully. Then *$ roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_playpen.launch* produces following error.
Error:
[husky_playpen.launch] is neither a launch file in package [husky_gazebo] nor is [husky_gazebo] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212160/i-have-installed-ros-(jade)-in-ubuntu-14.04.2-lts.-many-of-the-demo-packages-mentioned-in-the-tutorial-are-not-being-located-by-the-installed-ros.-please-let-me-know-if-i-am-missing-some-basic-steps./) by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2015-06-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-06-27**:
Please point to the tutorials your following, and provide full instructions for how to reproduce as well as copy and paste of all the commands your running and their console outputs so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First off, if you installed Jade, by doing "apt-get install ros-**indigo**-husky-navigation" you are going to get asked if you would like ros indigo to be installed. You can't mix and match distro's and package's when you install debian's say like from apt-get. If your enviornment is sourced to jade, then you should only use jade debian installed packages. If you installed from source, i recommend having one build in a jade catkin ws and another build of same source in a indigo catkin ws.

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2015-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess there are a lot of packages still missing for jade.
They have to be released for jade from their maintainers.
So I guess they are probably just not there yet.

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3